# Remove specific App listener in Capacitorjs

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

My capacitorjs app's homescreen contains this code

```
onMount(() => {
    App.addListener('backButton', () => {
            App.exitApp();
    });

    return () => {
        App.removeAllListeners();
    };
});
```

According to the [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#api), it's the only way to remove App listeners. In my usecase I want to remove the `exitApp` on `backButton` listener when user leaves the homepage, but this code creates unexpected behavior, as it could remove other listeners.

How to remove only this listener specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a single listener like this (see [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#addlistenerbackbutton-)):

```js
const listener = await App.addListener('backButton', () => {
  App.exitApp();
});
listener.remove();
```